# how to change url text of a magento module which is display in address bar

Tags: magento-1.7, url, extensions

I am using store locator extension when I click on its link from home page its URL in address bar is looking like this www.mydomain/datta_store_locator but I want to change like this www.mydomain/storelocation how could I change this name

Answer (score 1):

Magento `is managed router name` from `frontName at config.xml` so,
 you need to change in frontName at your module config xml

```
<frontName>datta_store_locator</frontName
```

to

```
<frontName>storelocation</frontName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `config.xml` of the extension.
There should be something like this inside the `<frontend>` tag:

```
   <routers>
        <some_value_here>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Module_Name</module>
                <frontName>datta_store_locator</frontName> 
            </args>
        </some_value_here>
    </routers>
```

You need to change the value of `<frontName>` to what ever you need.